# Visual Studio 2017 failed to build a project because of .NETFramwork incompatibility

Tags: .net, visual-studio, csproj

I was trying to build a project from github (https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850) in visual studio 2017. There were no errors, however there was a warning, and output showed

> Rebuild All: 13 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped.

The warning said:

> "The primary reference "nunit.framework" could not be resolved because
>   it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This
>   is a higher version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". tests

So I found project's `.csproj` file, and compared it to a `.csproj` file from already successfully built project (also from github, also in VS 2017).
I found that there is no definition what version of .NETFramework in .csproj file of the failed project. So I simply added one, I just copied the line from already successfully built project.
The line is the last line in this picture, mentioning v4.5:

[image]

After saving the file, project was successfully built.

I have a few questions:

1. Why did this work?
2. Why did Visual Studio assume the targeted framework is v4.0 if noting is written in the file?
3. Can I somehow adjust Visual Studio's settings, so I wouldn't have to change .csproj files anymore?
4. Why was this not an error, it was only a warning, I was under impression that anything causing the project to fail is automatically considered an error?

Thank you!

Comment: Meh, expecting something reasonable to happen when the build system needs to deal with something as gross as a corrupted project file is wishful thinking.  Just let them know about it, use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: OK, will do that. And hopefully they will have some kind of solution.